# call static function in class in another helper function in the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a class in a file which contains another static functions that are called in another js files.

```js
module.export = class myClass{
  static create(){
    ...
  }
}

// helpers 
function callCreate(){
  ..
}
```

I want to call the static function of `myClass` in `callCreate` helper function. How can I do this?

Comment: static members of the class are accessed like: `Class.staticVar`. In you case, it will be `myClass.create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static members of the class are accessed like:

```js
class MyClass {

  property() {
    console.log('i am normal member');
  }

  static func() {
    console.log('i am static member');
  }

  static funcThis() {
    console.log('i am static member');
    console.log(this === MyClass); // true
    this.func(); // will run fine as a static member of a class
    this.property(); // will give error as a normal member of a class
  }

}

(new MyClass()).property();

MyClass.func();

MyClass.funcThis();
```

Static Members are directly accessed by the class name and are not linked with an object. Also, you can only use `static` member of the class inside of a static function.

**Notice:** As pointed out by *@FelixKling* inside the static function `this` will refer directly to the class.

**Tip:** Always use the `PascalCase` for naming your class.

Comment: *"That is the reason you cannot use `this` inside of the static function."* That's not quite right. Of course you can use `this` (in every function there is a `this`), but it will refer to `MyClass`.

Comment: @FelixKling, I think you want to say "*but it will **not** refer to MyClass*".

Comment: No. I meant what I said. Just put `console.log(this === MyClass);` inside the static method.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yeah, I was wrong. I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Calling methods "properties" seems semantically incorrect, if we're going to talk about proper naming conventions.